# is "$X_1,\ldots,X_n$ independent" equivalent to "$P'(\omega_1\ldots,\omega_n)=P(\omega_1)\cdot \ldots \dots P(\omega_n)$"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Sometimes it seems to me, that when we are considering independent variables on a sample space of the form $\Omega^n$, we use the assumed independence of variables to show that  $P'(\omega_1\ldots,\omega_n)=P(\omega_1)\cdot \ldots \dots P(\omega_n)$, where $P'$ is a yet unknown measure on $\Omega^n$.
Whereas I would find it natural (supposing we know of a probability distribution $P$ on $\Omega$) to instead  define a distribution on $\Omega^n$, derived from $P$ (as the multiplication of individual probabilities),  and then show that our $X_i$'s are indeed independent.
So why is the first way of doing it more commonly used and  hot do I show using the independence that $P'(\omega_1\ldots,\omega_n)=P(\omega_1)\cdot \ldots \dots P(\omega_n)$ ? (I managed to do it the other way around and show independence using the above product measure)

To end it with Russell: "My mathematical lecturers never showed me any reason to suppose probability theory was anything but a tissue of fallacies".

Comment: This is actually wildly amusing: It seems that the math.SE community reacts allergic to quotes or to criticism concerning the bad pedagogy (in notation) of probability theory. Or is it forbidden to let the frustration created the bad formalism of a subfield of maths to transpire ? Anyway, keep them downvotes comming :) If someone wants to downvote my other question, let me make it easy for him, by providing a link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272181/what-does-it-mean-for-a-random-variable-to-describe-an-experiment

Comment: I think as a rule of thumb, it's helpful for readers if you clearly pin down a question. For example, if you were to ask, is the latter approach, which I find more natural (me too!), commonly used? (the answer is yes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure )

Comment: @uncookedfalcon Ok, I tried to be more precise. In the link you provided indeed it's explained how to construct a product measure, but the connection with independent variables isn't treated (which is the thing I don't quite understand - edited my question). Also - good to know there are also other people who find this latter approach more natural :). Were you also so frustrated with probability and the extremely sloppy way of handling the formalism ? (Do you perhaps know an undergraduate book -  i.e. without hard measure theory - that is formally more sound ?)

Comment: If I go to, say, StackOverflow and ask a programming question and end it with "C++ is a stupid language and it makes no sense and it sucks", I shouldn't be surprised if it makes people less interested in helping me understand C++. You should consider whether your "criticism" has any more substance than this.

Comment: @RahulNarain Well, I didn't say that probability is stupid and it sucks. I said it more elegantly with a quote :D (And why are uninterested people always downvoting ?) But jokes aside, what I'm criticising is that after having browsed through dozens of web pages - and this forum too!! - I always find the same sloppy way of handling matters in probability theory: Usually a sample isn't given - but we aren't told either that we should assume one fixed space exists. But if we do assume an arbitrary, in the next line, we see that this space actually does have to fulfill certain criteria such that

Comment: the variables on it make sense (the sample space for example has to have more elements in it than the values the random variable can take). This "physicists approach" of adding assumptions to our objects of consideration during our reasoning is just terrible (for me at least).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this isn't even the real quote (Russel says something like this about calculus, but probably sort of of means unease with foundations of math in general). Changing the quote to probability kinda sorta might be perceived as you talking as if you were Russel, on top of critizinh a rather beautiful - and rigorous - mathematical discipline which will be the chosen focus of the live of some people on here. That this steps on some toes, shouldn't surprise.

Comment: @gnometorule Well, true, though if adults whose area of expertise gets criticised  do a "revenge-downvote", act a bit like they were kindergarten I think. Since the question itself, it seems to me, was up to the standards more or less (at least, I've see worse questions with a positive vote count).

Comment: -1. Ignorance is not an excuse for arrogance.

Comment: @did But doing "revenge-downvotes" based on "moral-jduge" decisions and not mathematics *is* a consequence of a [see comment above]-type behavior ;) Is arrogant mathematics worse mathematics ?

Comment: Quite typically, the subject of votes seems to obsess you. You probably presume that I downvoted your post by revenge (whatever that means). Not so. I did it because your post is full of arrogant and stunningly uninformed proclamations which make for a bad question.

Comment: @did I can see your viewpoint, but I have to object to "quite typically" and "full of": I only posted two questions, so you can't possibly know me that well to say "typically" (and if a lot of people downvote I think it's natural I respond to that).

Comment: Concerning the "full of": *One* quote, that you may view as arrogant (although it was a comment out of frustration - you shouldn't confuse arrogance with frustration) doesn't make my question full of arrogance. Besides the quote, the rest of it is a neutral mathematical enquiry. Also, a lot of other questions  here on this site are uninformed (no need to hyperbolize it), so either you should downvote all of them or restrict to downvote because of my "arrogance" - which would again make me ask the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to why it's more commonly used, I can't say...for example, when I was learning this stuff I saw these in the opposite order.

To be clear, for what follows, we are in the case that $\Omega$ is finite (or countably infinite), so that you can recover what $P$ does to arbitrary subsets of $\Omega$ from what it does to singletons (by $P(S) = \sum_{s \in S} P(s)$). (otherwise the implication $P'(\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n) = P(\omega_1) \ldots P(\omega_n) \Rightarrow X_i$ are independent doesn't hold: if say $n = 2, \Omega = \mathbb{R}$ with $P$ given by integrating a cdf, the probability of any point is 0, so all we know about $P'$ is that it gives no weight to individual points)

For the desired implication, what does it mean that the "variables" are independent? Well, the $i^{th}$ variable $X_i: \Omega^n \rightarrow \Omega$ is simply  projection onto the $i^{th}$ coordinate.

Now then, to see what $P'$ of $(\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n)$ is, we note that this point is exactly the subset of $\Omega^n$ where $X_1 = \omega_1  \ldots X_n = \omega_n$. So by independence $$P'(X_1 = \omega_1 \cap \ldots \cap X_n = \omega_n) = \prod_i P'(X_i = \omega_i)$$

So it looks we want not just the independence of the $X_i$, but also that $P'(X_i = \omega) = P(\omega)$ for all $\omega$ and $i$ to get the desired result.

Comment: Great! And another example where the books are sloppy, since - as you say - the assumption $P'(v_I=\omega)=P(\omega)$ should also have been made. (upvoting takes 15 rep, and since a lot of people downvote me, I'll probably have to wait until I can upvote).

Comment: regarding this and your earlier comment (and my experience learning probability), I'm thinking this isn't the fault of "probability theory" or "books" in general, but rather just the book you're using :)! maybe try checking out grimmett & stirzaker's probability and random processes - I recall it being pretty good, while avoiding measure theory. no worries about the upvote lol